# Haskell analog of lisp backquoting and splicing

Tags: haskell, lisp, template-haskell, quasiquotes

In some lisps (e.g. [elisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote), [common lisp](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/macros.html)) there is a feature called backquoting.

It allows to construct a list while evaluating or splicing into it some elements. For example:

```lisp
 `(1 2 (3 (+ 4 5))) 
  ⇒ (1 2 (3 (+ 4 5)))  ; just quoted unevaluated list

 `(1 2 (3 ,(+ 4 5)))
  ⇒ (1 2 (3 9))     ; (+ 4 5) has been evaluated

 `(1 2 ,@(list 3 (+ 4 5)))
  ⇒ (1 2 3 9)       ; (3 9) has been spliced into the list
```

I guess, in Haskell some subset of backquoting could look like this:

```
 [backquote| 1, 2, @$(replicate 2 3), 2 + 2 |]
 ⇒ [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

I wonder, if splicing into list like this is possible and if it has been implemented.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192240/discussion-on-question-by-grepcake-haskell-analog-of-lisp-backquoting).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the discussion in the comments kind of went off the rails.  Anyway, I have a different take on this, so let me offer an answer.

I would say that Haskell already has a feature analogous to backquoting, and you've probably used it extensively in your own Haskell programming without realizing it.

You've drawn a parallel between Lisp lists and Haskell lists, but in Lisp, S-expression (i.e., "pairs with atoms", especially with atomic symbols) are a flexible and ubiquitous data structure, used not only for representing Lisp code, but also as the go-to representation that's at least the first consideration for any complex, structured data.  As such, most Lisp programs spend a lot of time generating and manipulating these structures, and so S-expression "literals" are common in Lisp code.  And, S-expression "almost literals", where a few sub-expressions need to be calculated, are more conveniently written using the backquoting mechanism than trying to build up the expression with smaller literal and evaluated pieces using functions like `cons`, `list`, `append`, etc.

Contrast that with Haskell --  Haskell lists are certainly popular in Haskell code, and are a go-to structure for representing homogeneous sequences, but they provide only a small fraction of the flexibility of S-expressions.  Instead, the corresponding ubiquitous data structure in Haskell is the Algebraic Data Type (ADT).

Well, just like Lisp with its S-expressions, Haskell programs spend a lot of time generating and manipulating ADTs, and Haskell also has a convenient syntax for ADT literals and "almost literals".  They are unified into a single "function application" syntax with literal and evaluated parts differentiated by the use of constructors (identifiers with an initial uppercase letter or infix operators starting with a colon) versus non-constructors (identifiers with an initial lowercase letter or infix operators without an initial colon).  There is, of course, some additional syntax for certain constructors (lists and tuples).

For example, compare the following backquoted expressions in Lisp and Haskell:

```
;; Lisp
(setq baz `(node ,id
                 (node ,(+ id 1) ,left-tree leaf)
                 (node ,(+ id 2) leaf ,right-tree)))
-- Haskell
baz = Node id (Node (id + 1) left_tree Leaf) (Node (id + 2) Leaf right_tree)
```

In the Haskell version of this "almost literal", the `Node` and `Leaf` constructors represent the quoted parts; the `left-tree`, `right-tree`, and `+` infix expression represent the evaluated parts, and they are syntactically distinguishable by the usual rules for constructors and non-constructors.

Of course, completely separate from this, there's a Template Haskell mechanism that directly manipulates snippets of Haskell code at compile time.  While the code is represented as an ADT that could, in principle, be written using the same "almost literal" syntax used for other ADTs, the ADT in question is quite cumbersome and looks nothing like the underlying Haskell code.  So, Template Haskell provides a more classic sort of backquoting syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer, but you are focusing completely on semi-evaluation feature of backquoting, which is somewhat trivial in Haskell. However, the most interesting part is splicing. I mentioned it the discussion, but I guess I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: If that is backquoting, then Lisp without backquote also has backquoting. Look!   `(make-node id (make-node (+ id 1) left-tree 'leaf) (make-node (+ id 2) ...) ...)`.

Comment: > *Node and Leaf constructors represent the quoted parts ..*  Not as **symbols**, though.

Comment: This looks like the beginning of long, painful "discussion in the comments", so consider this clarifying remark my absolute last word on the subject.  IMHO, Haskell constructors and functions are quite different objects, even though they have some superficial similarities, and that's the point I was making.  A constructor is more like a (quoted) Lisp symbol than a Lisp function -- think of it as a "self-quoting" symbol.  So, in Haskell, you get back-quoting "for free" because there is a syntactic distinction between self-quoting symbols and functions.